# Suborganizations and Unique id

Tags: ldap, spring-ldap, apacheds

I can succesfully authenticate my application with ApacheDS

But now i use only one domain.

I want to add subdomains or sub organizations under root domain.

For example a root organization as

```
dc=example,dc=com
```

and sub organizations `dc=x`

another sub organization `dc=y`

Now i can authenticate users using uid attribute

like:

```
user-search-filter="(uid={0})"
```

i use login name like user1, without an @ extension

But i want to have suborganizations and i want to use user1@x.example.com

Is it possible and how?

My application is a spring application but i think subject is independent from my application side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attribute defined in the LDAP standards track for email addresses is `mail`, `rfc822mailbox`, or `0.9.2342.19200300.100.1.3` as defined in [RFC4524](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4524#section-2.16). Perhaps your filter should be an attribute assertion using one of those types, for example, `user-search-filter="mail={0}"`.

I am not sure what is meant by "manually". LDAP does not have a concept of organizations, only entries that might belong to an `organization`. These entries might have a `mail` attribute if the entry belongs to an `objectClass` that allows or requires the `mail` attribute. In other words, if your filter is `mail={0}` (which might become `mail=user1@x.example.com`), then a search using that filter (given the appropriate base object and scope) will return all entries that have a `mail` attribute with the value `user1@x.example.com` irrespective of where that user is located and irrespective of the value of the `uid` attribute.

If the users in an organization can identified some other way, perhaps by organization or other attribute, then the filter could be:

```
(&(uid={0})(o=x))
```

or

```
(&(uid={0})(o=y))
```

One way or another, the users' entry must be identifiable by the contents of the entry. The primary key in an LDAP database is the *distinguished name* (`uid=abc,dc=x,dc=example,dc=com`) but attributes in the entry can be used to tighten the filter. Some alternatives are:

- use unique identifiers (all `uid` or `mail` values are unique in the database, therefore, only one is ever returned to a search request)
- use an attribute to identify users in an organization (like `o` in the example filters above)
- use a dynamic group to generate a list of users in an organization.
- consider using an extensible match filter to make values in the distinguished names be part of the filtering process

#### see also

- [using ldapsearch](http://ff1959.wordpress.com/2011/07/27/mastering-ldapsearch/) - the article is about the `ldapsearch` command line tool, but the concepts are useful when constructing search requests
- [mastering search filters](http://ff1959.wordpress.com/2011/09/21/mastering-ldap-search-filters/)

Comment: Thanks very much for the reply. Then, do i have to manage manually, the mail attributes' extension after @ , corresponding to my dc=sth dn which has my user as a child?

Comment: Can i put an automatic value as mail maybe, $uid@$dn. Or sth like it. It is ugly i know but may it be possible?

Comment: I do not know how your application works, therefore I cannot answer.

Comment: i wonder if i can write such an expression as an attribute of one of my entries in ApacheDS. I think it is not possible, it is like being a day dreamer. Thanks for patience